# Odd behavior of int(x) in python

Tags: python, floating-point, int

When running this program,

```
cost = 12
money = 12.51
change = money - cost

dollars = int(change)
change -= dollars

quarters = int(change / 0.25)
change -= quarters * 0.25

dimes = int(change / 0.1)
change -= dimes * 0.1

nickels = int(change / 0.05)
change -= nickels * 0.05

pennies = int(change / 0.01)

print("""Your change is:
    %i dollars
    %i quarters
    %i dimes
    %i nickels
    %i pennies
""" % (dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies))
```

The output is

```
Your change is:
    0 dollars
    2 quarters
    0 dimes
    0 nickels
    0 pennies
```

Why is pennies 0? I've tried printing pennies separately, same thing happens. I know for certain as well that `change / 0.01` is equal to `1.0`. For some reason, it seems that `int(1.0)` is equal to `0`. Obviously, it's not. Maybe `1.0` is a floating point number that isn't actually 1 and gets floored to `0`?

Sidenote: Removing int function on pennies and replacing with `%.0f pennies` works.

I guess this is exactly what people talk about when they say not to use floating point numbers when working with money. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My completed code:

```
cost = input("What is the cost in dollars? ")
money = input("Money given: ")
change = int(round(money - cost) * 100)

if change < 0:
    print("You didn't pay enough!")
    exit()

dollars = change / 100
change %= 100

quarters = change / 25
change %= 25

dimes = change / 10
change %= 10

nickels = change / 5
change %= 5

pennies = change

print("""Your change is:
    %i dollars
    %i quarters
    %i dimes
    %i nickels
    %i pennies
""" % (dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies))
```

Comment: The result of `round(money - cost, 2)` is still an approximation, since it is in units of hundredths of a dollar, and 1/100 is not exactly representable in binary floating-point. `change = round((money - cost) * 100)` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

> I know for certain as well that change / 0.01 is equal to 1.0

Well, not quite. If you try doing `change / 0.01` directly from the Python interpreter, it returns something like `0.99999999999787` due to floating point errors. Naturally, if you try converting that to an int, it'll round down to zero.

To avoid this, you could try one of two things. You could either try using the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module from Python, which does avoid floating point errors like these, or you could multiply `change` by 100 at the very beginning so you're dealing with integer values, not floating point numbers, and modify the rest of your code accordingly.

Comment: Cool. I thought that'd be what's going on. It's weird that python will print `1.0` when doing `change / 0.01`. Pretty misleading if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

`%.0f` performs rounding on numbers, while `%i` does not do so. Also, learn math!